# Java Servlets, JSP and data transfer between two clients

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, websocket

Im new to Java EE and I want to build a basic web application.

I want to allow two clients(in a multiplayer quiz game) to see the others answer to quiz questions simultaneously. Both are aware of the other one's time and score.

I have no idea how this is done. Are there some specific classes and methods about this so I can learn, or is there an example code connecting clients? Sorry for a little vague question. Thank you!

Comment: uhm... client side without server side @ java??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using WebSockets. If you are in a Java EE context (and you say you are) then the web sockets API is available to you, if it's Java EE 7 or more.

With web sockets, your (Java EE) server side can push the game data to each of your (HTML5) clients.

Using WebSockets your clients do not have to issue any HTTP requests in order to see the latest game data. The server (..the server which you must write) can push the data when appropriate.